# Identify the interior and boundary of the set $|\mathbf{x}-(1,2)|\le 0.5$

Tags: real-analysis

I've just started a book on real-analysis; It's asking me to identify the interior and boundary of some sets in $R^2$ that have been given to me. I have to show that they are open or closed -

$|\mathbf{x}-(1,2)|\le 0.5$

I know this is an $\epsilon$-**ball** with radius $0.5$ and centre (1, 2).

I can expand the LHS to get:

$\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2}\le0.5$

What should I be looking out for to show that this set is either within the interior or the boundary? I know it's a closed set because of the equality sign - my assumptions next are to simplify both sides, is this the approach to take?

Comment: If $\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2} = 0.5$, then the point is on the boundary.  If $\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2} < 0.5$, then the point is on the interior.  By the way, your question has a minor analytical error, re the center of the circle is $(1,2)$, rather than $(1,1).$

Comment: For what it's worth, in Complex Analysis, variables are normally referred to as $z = x + iy$, so that the variable $z$ is not confused with $x$ or $y$.  Unless your book is specifically using $X$ to represent elements $(x,y)$ in $\Bbb{R^2}$, I suggest using the same convention of referring to the variables as $z$, rather than $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S$ be your set. The interior is exactly the set of points $p\in \mathbb R^2$ such that there is an open ball $p\in B(p,r) \subseteq S$, and the boundary is exactly the set of points $p\in \mathbb R^2$ such that every ball $B(p,r)$ intersects non-trivially with $S$ and the complement $\mathbb R^2 \setminus S$.

Suppose now we have $y \in \mathbb R^2$ with $|y-(1,2)|<0.5$. Let us call this constant distance $d := |y-(1,2)|$.Then, I claim that the ball $B(y,0.5-d) \subseteq S$, meaning that $y$ is in the interior of $S$. This is by the triangle inequality: if $z\in B(y,0.5-d)$, then
$$|z-(1,2)| = |z-y + y - (1,2)| \leq |z-y| + |y-(1,2)| < (0.5-d) + d=0.5,$$
or in other words $z\in S$. As $z\in B(y,0.5-d)$ was arbitrary, this proves that $B(y,0.5-d) \subseteq S$. Now as $y \in \mathbb R^2$ with $|y-(1,2)|<0.5$ was arbitrary, we have proven that $\{y \in \mathbb R^2 : |y-(1,2)|<0.5\}$ is contained in the interior of $S$.

Now suppose now we have $y \in \mathbb R^2$ with $|y-(1,2)|=0.5$. By definition of $S$, we know that $y\in S$, so to prove that $y$ is in the boundary of $S$, we show that every ball around $y$ intersects with the outside of $S$, i.e. $\mathbb R^2 \setminus S$. Let $B(y,r)$ be arbitrary ball around $y$. Then, thinking of the line segment from $(1,2)$ to $y$, we can add a bit to the end of the segment at $y$ of length $\frac r2$; this "nudged" version of $y$ lies outside of $S$. Now as $y \in \mathbb R^2$ with $|y-(1,2)|=0.5$ was arbitrary, we have proven that $\{y \in \mathbb R^2 : |y-(1,2)|=0.5\}$ is contained in the boundary of $S$.

Finally, for $y \in \mathbb R^2$ with $|y-(1,2)|>0.5$, there is always a ball around $y$ that doesn't intersect with $S$ at all (the argument is very similar to the triangle inequality one above). Thus, these $y$ are not in the interior or boundary, meaning that $\{y \in \mathbb R^2 : |y-(1,2)|<0.5\}$ is EXACTLY the interior of $S$ and similarly $\{y \in \mathbb R^2 : |y-(1,2)|=0.5\}$ is EXACTLY the boundary of $S$.